# Repeat Array while Maintaining Order within group

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the below `array` and would like to `repeat` each `array` `n` times.

```
x_array

[array([14.91488012,  1.2986064 ,  4.98965322]),
 array([2.39389187e+02, 1.04442059e-01, 3.06391338e-01]),
 array([ 48.19437348, 201.09951372,   0.35223001]),
 array([ 19.96978171, 367.52578786,   0.68676553]),
 array([0.55120466, 0.27133609, 0.75646697]),
 array([8.21287360e+02, 1.76495077e+02, 4.87263691e-01]),
 array([184.03439377,   1.24823107,   5.33109884]),
 array([575.59800297, 186.4650814 ,   2.21028258]),
 array([0.50308552, 3.09976082, 0.10537899]),
 array([1.02259912e+00, 1.52282513e+02, 1.15085308e-01])]
```

I've tried `np.repeat(x_array, 2)` but this doesn't preserve the order of the `matrix`/`array`. I've also tried `x_array*2`, but this seems to just put the new array at the bottom. I was hopping to repeat `x_array[0]` `n` times and do the same for the next set of `arrays`, so that I have `n` total of each in order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is is a list?

Comment: That's currently how I have the data set up so that I can loop through it.

Comment: You know you can loop through rows of an ndarray, right? Maybe this isn't relevant to the question, but it's still worth thinking about.

Comment: I've tried a `for` loop as well and did not get the results I was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the *axis*:

```
>>> np.repeat(x_array, 2, axis=0)
array([[1.49149e+01, 1.29861e+00, 4.98965e+00],
       [1.49149e+01, 1.29861e+00, 4.98965e+00],
       [2.39389e+02, 1.04442e-01, 3.06391e-01],
       [2.39389e+02, 1.04442e-01, 3.06391e-01],
       ...,
       [5.03086e-01, 3.09976e+00, 1.05379e-01],
       [5.03086e-01, 3.09976e+00, 1.05379e-01],
       [1.02260e+00, 1.52283e+02, 1.15085e-01],
       [1.02260e+00, 1.52283e+02, 1.15085e-01]])
```

From [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

> `numpy.repeat(a, repeats, axis=None)`
>
> ...
>
> **axis** *int*, *optional*
> The axis along which to repeat values. **By default, use the flattened input array, and return a flat output array.**

(added bold)

Answer (score 2):

Building off of the last example from https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html,

```
x_array = np.array(x_array) # Or a similiar operation to convert x_array to an ndarray vs. a list of arrays.   
expanded_x_array = np.repeat(x_array, n, axis=0)
print(expanded_x_array)
```

should produce what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```py
n = 2
repeated_list = [row for row in a for _ in range(n)]
print(repeated_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is confusing.  You say it's an "array", but the display looks more like a list,  And the fact that `x_array*2` puts an "new array" at the bottom confirms that - that's a list use of `*`.

`np.repeat(x_array)` first makes an array (a real one!)

```
np.array(x_array)
```

is a (n,3) float dtype array.  Without `axis` `np.repeat` flattens - as documented!

Specifying the `axis=0` works because it's repeating on that first `n` dimension.  The result is a (2*n,3) float dtype array (not a list).

It is possible to make a 1d object dtype array containing those arrays.  With that `repeat` will work without the axis parameter.

Knowing what you have, and describing it accurately, can make this kind of task much easier - and the questions clearer.

### illustration

Make a list of arrays:

```
In [21]: alist = [np.ones(3,int),np.zeros(3,int),np.arange(3)]
In [22]: alist
Out[22]: [array([1, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2])]
```

List repeat:

```
In [23]: alist*2
Out[23]: 
[array([1, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 1, 2]),
 array([1, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 1, 2])]
```

Make a 2d array from the list:

```
In [24]: np.array(alist)
Out[24]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

repeat without axis repeats elements in a flattened way:

```
In [25]: np.repeat(alist,2)
Out[25]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

repeat this 2d array on 0 axis:

```
In [26]: np.repeat(alist,2,axis=0)
Out[26]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Object dtype array from list:

```
In [27]: arr = np.empty(3,object); arr[:]=alist
In [28]: arr
Out[28]: array([array([1, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

Since the arrays have the same size we have to use this special construct.  Otherwise we get the 2d array [24].

This array has a `repeat` method, and with only one dimension we dont need to specify the axis.  It's repeating the object elements, arrays, not the numbers in the 2d [24] array.

```
In [29]: arr.repeat(2)
Out[29]: 
array([array([1, 1, 1]), array([1, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0]),
       array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
```